# Can Magento API create products with new attribute?

Tags: magento

Can Magento API create products with new attribute? I mean some attributes of the product not in the default system. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a product with a new attribute or a new attribute itself by the Magento API. [Reference](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api).